# Automating a third party application - Systreeview32 reports 0 items, yet has nodes

Tags: winapi, treeview, zero

I am working to automate several applications. One depends on the output of another.
The problem I am running into is that when I try to access the `Treeview` to get additional info, the count returns 0.

If I look at it visibly, it show quite a few items.
If I look at it with Winspector, it reports 0 visible items.

How can I gather this info? This is the info that is gathered dynamically and from several places. I cannot access the databases (that would be nice, but since some of the info is dynamic, it is not possible).

Here is the output that Winspector gives me:

```
Properties for window: 0x00021806   

Class Name:         SysTreeView32 

Rectangle:          213, 180, 1038, 375 

Size:               825, 195 

Client Rectangle:   0, 0, 821, 191 

Client Size:        821, 191 

Styles:             WS_CHILD,
                    WS_VISIBLE,
                    WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
                    WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
                    WS_TABSTOP,

StylesEx:           WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY,
                    WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                    WS_EX_LEFT,
                    WS_EX_LTRREADING,
                    WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR

ID:                 0

Properties:         Atom: #43288 0xFFFFFFFF (-1)

Class specific:     Visible items:0, 
                    Total items: 0
                    Window is Ansi

Owner EXE           c:\csg\acsr\XBOI.EXE
```

Any ideas how I can retrieve the node info and items?
I am using VBA (access) with API calls with sendmessage.

Here is my code that I am using to test item count:

```
Sub testtree(mytv As Long)

Dim z As Long

Dim wClass As String, wText As String

    Dim hWndTvw  As Long

    Dim hNode As Long

    Dim varReturn As Long

    Dim tvcount As Long

    Dim hchild As Long

    Dim j As Integer

    hchild = mytv

    wClass = Space(64)

    j = GetClassName(hchild, wClass, 63)

    wClass = Left(wClass, j)

    wText = Space(256)

    j = SendMessageS(hchild, WM_GETTEXT, 255, wText)

    wText = Left(wText, j)

    Debug.Print wText

z = SendMessage(mytv, TVM_GETCOUNT, 0&, 0&)

MsgBox z

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [TVM_GETNEXTITEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to enumerate the tree's nodes: first call it with TVGN_ROOT flag to get the root node, then use TVGN_CHILD and TVGN_NEXT flags to walk through the nodes. This message returns you the item's handle.

When you've got the item's handle, use [TVM_GETITEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to retrieve the associated data you're interested in (e.g. item's text).

You should read that 2 links carefully for more info on using that messages.

P.S. The problem is, the TVM_GETITEM message uses TVITEM structure with pointers, and I'm not sure it'll be easy to use from the VBA (unlike e.g. C, C++, even C#/VB.NET is IMO more suitable for that). In the worst case (i.e. unless you know something about the VBA I'm not aware of: last time I've dealt with VBA was about 2004), you'll need to develop a small COM object using C++/ATL for this single task, and redistrubute & register it along with your software. Or look for the 3-rd party components.

Comment: As for the issue of writting a COM, I am not familiar with doing that. I HAVE been for the most part successful decaling an API function and then using it to communicate with a program in a different memory space.